# How to specifiy MonoRemoteDebugger application folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, mono, remote-debugging

I'm using [MonoRemoteDebugger](https://github.com/techl/MonoRemoteDebugger) to develop an app remotely in C#/Mono from Visual Studio 2017 on a Raspberry Pi/Raspbian.

I've noticed that the app is placed inside a Temp folder, in MonoRemoteDebuggerServer folder.

I was wondering if it's possible to configure MonoRemoteDebugger to place the app in a **specified folder**. If so, then how?